# Paypal PHP SDK Payout in Laravel

Tags: php, paypal

I am getting

> PayPal \ Exception \ PayPalConnectionException (500)

I am getting Http response code 500 when accessing *https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?* when I try to process a batch payout with Pypal PHP SDK

Here is My Controller:

```
private $_api_context;
public function __construct()
{
    /** setup PayPal api context **/
    $paypal_conf = Config::get('paypal');
    $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['client_secret']));
    $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
}

public function batchPayout(){
    $payouts    =   new Payout();
    $senderBatchHeader  = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader();

    $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
        ->setEmailSubject("You have a ");

    $senderItem1    =   new PayoutItem();
    $senderItem1->setRecipientType('Email')
        ->setNote("New Payment")
        ->setReceiver('xxx@gmail.com')
        ->setSenderItemId(uniqid())
        ->setAmount(new Currency('{
        "value":"99",
        "currency":"USD"
        }'));

    $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader)
        ->addItem($senderItem1);

    $request    =   clone $payouts;

    try{
        $output =   $payouts->create(null, $this->_api_context);
    }catch (Exception $ex){
        return $ex->getMessage();
    }
    return $output;
}}
```

Comment: Kindly help with this

Comment: It worked without changing the code!!!. I think the problem might have been the Paypal's API at that time.

Comment: I have getting same error. It is working on localhost But not working on server. before this line ->setAmount(new Currency('{ code get stop.